# How create GPS Tools?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I try display Google Maps inside my Fragment. The problem is when I run my project I do not see this maps. The additional information is this fragments belongs to Pager View.

This is my sample of code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        thisContext = inflater.getContext();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);
        loadMap();
       // initializeMap();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) thisContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return null;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);

        return view;

    }


    private void initializeMap() {
        if (map == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    private void loadMap() {
        SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;

        mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
        }

        if (mSupportMapFragment != null) {
            mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    if (googleMap != null) {

                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

                        // -> marker_latlng // MAKE THIS WHATEVER YOU WANT

                        //CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(marker_latlng).zoom(15.0f).build();
                        // CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
                        // googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I run my project I do not see this maps.

You can use the default 'new Activity' wizard to create Google maps activity.
It includes all the information you need. See the 7th item in the following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best thing so far I know for Fragment is to use `MapView` instead of `MapFragment`. I am using `MapView` inside a `Navigation Drawer` Fragment and its working fine with all `callbacks` that I need and `PlacesAutoComplete`.